# Oscurecer pantalla al mostrar alertdialog

Tags: java, android

estoy intentando familiarizarme con el comportamiento de los alertdialog de cara a un futuro proyecto del módulo de aplicaciones móviles. El caso es que,EN TEORÍA, por defecto los dialogos al mostrarse hacen que la pantalla detras de ellos se oscurezca, para que el usuario se focalice en el dialogo, sin embargo, por alguna razón, no consigo que se de este comportamiento. Asimismo he tratado de implementar ese comportamiento de forma manual de MUCHAS maneras y consultando múltiples fuentes: you tube, la pagina android developers... sin éxito. A ver si me podéis ayudar :(

Adjunto codigo

```
`package com.example.pruebadialogos;


 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     Button boton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        boton=findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                       new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                 builder.setMessage("Esto es un mensaje de alerta.")
                        .setTitle("Información")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                               new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                                       dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog dialogo=builder.create();
                 builder.show();
              }
          });
       }
    }`








 //Esta es mi main activity, tan solo tiene un button


    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">


     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`

 //El xml de la main activity


   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#fffacd"
     app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
   >
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="350dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/layouttoast"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/biscuit"
               android:layout_width="100dp"
               android:layout_height="100dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              android:background="@drawable/biscuitmolesto" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mensaje"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
               android:fontFamily="@font/akceleraaltmedium"
               android:text=""
               android:textColor="#FF0000"
               android:textFontWeight="50"
               android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/aceptar"
            android:text="ACEPTAR"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:textColor="#660099"

          />
    </LinearLayout>

  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>`

  //El xml de la vista personalizada del dialogo
```

Además, ya que soy nuevo en StackOverflow, agradecería que me lo hicieseis saber si hay alguna regla en cuanto a formato y presentacion de las preguntas que esté incumpliendo y deba conocer. Gracias de antemano :)